# ray: installation anyscale-academy tutorial throw socket exception

Tags: ray

When install ray, distributed ML framework, I install ray 1.0.1post on VM with centOS 8.2. I follow [the official document](https://github.com/anyscale/academy) step by step, the I issue the command to launch tutorial web server:

```
> jupyter lab
```

I got exception, something similar as follows:

```
"/usr/lib64/xxx/tornado/netutil.py", line 196, in bind_sockets sock.bind(sockaddr)
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

How to fix this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception is not related to ray, it is because CentOS default allows partial IPv4, IPv6, so either enable IPv6，or disable IPv6 explicitly. It works. Also one need to disable firewalld to let outside client to access VM web server.

The following command helps to enable IPv6,

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=0
```

The following command to stop firewalld:

```
systemctl status firewalld
systemctl stop fiewalld
```

if in the status command: one see running keyword, it means firewalld is running, after stopping, one see the key word dead:

```
Running:
 Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-03-19 10:17:27 CST; 4 days ago  
Dead: 
 Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2021-03-23 10:58:10 CST; 3s ago
```